# Plz someone tell me how to solve this problem

Tags: react-native

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> 4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.2.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - file:/C:/Users/anees/.m2/repository/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.2.0/fresco-2.2.0.pom
> - file:/R:/project_01/node_modules/react-native/android/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.2.0/fresco-2.2.0.pom
> - file:/R:/project_01/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.2.0/fresco-2.2.0.pom
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.2.0/fresco-2.2.0.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.2.0/fresco-2.2.0.pom
> - https://www.jitpack.io/com/facebook/fresco/fresco/2.2.0/fresco-2.2.0.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.75.1
> project :app > com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:0.75.1 > com.facebook.fresco:flipper:2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Change your fresco version to 2.3.0.
This worked for me.

Comment: how and where ?

Comment: @CodeBy Probably 0.75.1

Answer (score 1):

you should update your FLIPPER_VERSION inside gradle.proprties file

Comment: to which version?

Answer (score 0):

add this in android/app/build.gradle

```
     implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0'
     implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.0.0'

     debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco- 
    plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
     }
```

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'R:\project_01\android\build.gradle' line: 46

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'R:\project_01\android\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'R:\project_01\android\build.gradle': 46: Unexpected input: 'debugImplementation("' @ line 46, column 21.
     debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-
                         ^

Comment: brother can u help me to out this